# We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again. (line 63, file "Code")

Tags: google-apps-script

Thank you in advance for helping.

I am trying to convert the most recent submitted data from Google Form/Google sheets to a "template" Google doc. Basically, when a user submit a form, it will convert the data from Google Sheet and create a new Google Doc.

Side note: Im not really a coder.. I found the base script online and tried to modified it accordingly. I would greatly appreciate a step by step if possible?

AGAIN, THANK YOU SO MUCH

```js
function createDocument() {
  var headers = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('SHEET-ID', 'A1:AU1');
var tactics = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('SHEET-ID', 'A2:AU2');
var templateId = 'DOCTEMPLATE-ID';
  
  for(var i = 0; i < tactics.values.length; i++){
    
    var Fclient = tactics.values[i][0];
    var Lclient = tactics.values[i][1];
    var birthday = tactics.values[i][2];
    var profession = tactics.values[i][3];
    var email = tactics.values[i][4];
    var phone = tactics.values[i][5];
    var whatsapp = tactics.values[i][6];
    var preferredcontact = tactics.values[i][7];
    var UScitizen = tactics.values[i][8];
    var Ocitizen = tactics.values[i][9];
    var Tsapre = tactics.values[i][10];
    var Pairplane = tactics.values[i][11];
    var Photelamen = tactics.values[i][12];
    var FFlyer = tactics.values[i][13];
    var hotelloy = tactics.values[i][14];
    var vistedcountries = tactics.values[i][15];
    var smoke = tactics.values[i][16];
    var allergies = tactics.values[i][17];
    var Othermed = tactics.values[i][18];
    var addANOTHER = tactics.values[i][19];
    var emergencyname = tactics.values[i][20];
    var emergencyphone = tactics.values[i][21];
    var emergencyrelation = tactics.values[i][22];
    var emergencyname2 = tactics.values[i][23];
    var emergencyphone2 = tactics.values[i][24];
    var emergencyrelation2 = tactics.values[i][25];
    var comptravelmag = tactics.values[i][26];
    var secondaryFname = tactics.values[i][27];
    var secondaryLname = tactics.values[i][28];
    var secondarybirthday = tactics.values[i][29];
    var secondaryprofession = tactics.values[i][30];
    var secondaryemail = tactics.values[i][31];
    var secondaryphone = tactics.values[i][32];
    var secondarywhatsapp = tactics.values[i][33];
    var secondarypreferredcontact = tactics.values[i][34];
    var secondaryUScitizen = tactics.values[i][35];
    var secondaryOcitizen = tactics.values[i][36];
    var secondaryTsapre = tactics.values[i][37];
    var secondaryPairplane = tactics.values[i][38];
    var secondaryPhotelamen = tactics.values[i][39];
    var secondaryFFlyer = tactics.values[i][40];
    var secondaryhotelloy = tactics.values[i][41];
    var secondaryvistedcountries = tactics.values[i][42];
    var secondarysmoke = tactics.values[i][43];
    var secondaryallergies = tactics.values[i][44];
    var secondaryOthermed = tactics.values[i][45];
       var timestamp = tactics.values[i][46];
    
    //Make a copy of the template file
    var documentId = DriveApp.getFileById(templateId).makeCopy().getId();
    
    //Rename the copied file
    DriveApp.getFileById(documentId).setName('Basic Information: ' + Lclient + 'test');
    
    //Get the document body as a variable. 
    var body = DocumentApp.openById(documentId).getBody(); **ERROR HERE**
    
    //Insert the supplier name
    body.replaceText('{{Fcilent}}', Fclient);
body.replaceText('{{Lcilent}}', Lclient);
body.replaceText('{{birthday}}', birthday);
body.replaceText('{{profession}}', profession);
body.replaceText('{{email}}', email);
body.replaceText('{{phone}}', phone);
body.replaceText('{{whatsapp}}', whatsapp);
body.replaceText('{{preferredcontact}}', preferredcontact);
body.replaceText('{{UScitizen}}', UScitizen);
body.replaceText('{{Ocitizen}}', Ocitizen);
body.replaceText('{{Tsapre}}', Tsapre);
body.replaceText('{{Pairplane}}', Pairplane);
body.replaceText('{{Photelamen}}', Photelamen);
body.replaceText('{{FFlyer}}', FFlyer);
body.replaceText('{{hotelloy}}', hotelloy);
body.replaceText('{{vistedcountries}}', vistedcountries);
body.replaceText('{{smoke}}', smoke);
body.replaceText('{{allergies}}', allergies);
body.replaceText('{{Othermed}}', Othermed);
body.replaceText('{{addANOTHER}}', addANOTHER);
body.replaceText('{{emergencyname}}', emergencyname);
body.replaceText('{{emergencyphone}}', emergencyphone);
body.replaceText('{{emergencyrelation}}', emergencyrelation);
body.replaceText('{{emergencyname2}}', emergencyname2);
body.replaceText('{{emergencyphone2}}', emergencyphone2);
body.replaceText('{{emergencyrelation2}}', emergencyrelation2);
body.replaceText('{{comptravelmag}}', comptravelmag);
body.replaceText('{{secondaryFname}}', secondaryFname);
body.replaceText('{{secondaryLname}}', secondaryLname);
body.replaceText('{{secondarybirthday}}', secondarybirthday);
body.replaceText('{{secondaryprofession}}', secondaryprofession);
body.replaceText('{{secondaryemail}}', secondaryemail);
body.replaceText('{{secondaryphone}}', secondaryphone);
body.replaceText('{{secondarywhatsapp}}', secondarywhatsapp);
body.replaceText('{{secondarypreferredcontact}}', secondarypreferredcontact);
body.replaceText('{{secondaryUScitizen}}', secondaryUScitizen);
body.replaceText('{{secondaryOcitizen}}', secondaryOcitizen);
body.replaceText('{{secondaryTsapre}}', secondaryTsapre);
body.replaceText('{{secondaryPairplane}}', secondaryPairplane);
body.replaceText('{{secondaryPhotelamen}}', secondaryPhotelamen);
body.replaceText('{{secondaryFFlyer}}', secondaryFFlyer);
body.replaceText('{{secondaryhotelloy}}', secondaryhotelloy);
body.replaceText('{{secondaryvistedcountries}}', secondaryvistedcountries);
body.replaceText('{{secondarysmoke}}', secondarysmoke);
body.replaceText('{{secondaryallergies}}', secondaryallergies);
body.replaceText('{{secondaryOthermed}}', secondaryOthermed);
body.replaceText('{{timestamp}}', timestamp); 
        
    //Append tactics
    parseTactics(headers.values[0], tactics.values[i], body);
    
  }

}

function parseTactics(headers, tactics, body){ 
  
  for(var i = 1; i < tactics.length; i++){
    {tactics[i] != '' && 
      body.appendListItem(headers[i] + ' | ' + tactics[i] + ' OTHER').setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET);
    }
    
  }
}
```

Error: "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again. (line 63, file "Code")"

I expected the script to generate a new google doc from the data sheet as it is being submitted on google form.

Answer (score 0):

I think your pretty close.  Here's an example I did.

First, I created a function to generate some data for myself.

```
function testData() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  sh.clearContents();
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,1,10,10);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<vA[i].length;j++) {
      vA[i][j]=Utilities.formatString('row: %s - col: %s',i+1,j+1);
    }
  }
  rg.setValues(vA);
}
```

The above function creates a sheet that looks like this:

[image]

The Template File Looks like this:

[image]

And after running this code:

```
function createDoc(){
  var spreadsheetId='spreadsheet Id';
  var templateId='template Id';
  var data=Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId,'Sheet177!A1:J2');//range include sheet name
  var docId=DriveApp.getFileById(templateId).makeCopy('Test').getId();
  var body=DocumentApp.openById(docId).getBody();

  for(var i=0;i<data.values.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<data.values[i].length;j++) {
      var s=Utilities.formatString('{{col%s-%s}}',i+1,j+1);
      body.replaceText(s,data.values[i][j]);
    }             
  }
}
```

There appears in the same folder another file named test that looks like this:

[image]

I must say that sure is a simple way to get data.

I'm kind of wondering if perhaps you simply didn't authenticate the program in the script editor.

Comment: Thank you Cooper, I've authenticated the Sheets API as well as giving the script permission to access the docs. It was working when I had the data listed with bullets, but once I added more of the "var ids" plus "replacetext" and edited  the templated doc into something more "organized" it showed that error. Is possible that the template is with too many placeholders? Currently I have it as: 
Name:  {{Fcilent}}                             Profession: {{profession}}
 Last: {{Lcilent}}                                Email: {{email}}
Birthday:  {{birthday}}      

two columns.

Comment: I don't think so.  They're just strings .